# React-native flatlist item layout should adapt device orientation change

Tags: react-native, orientation, landscape, device-orientation, flatlist

So I am creating flatlist of images. Which shows only one image at a time on the screen.
Now if I rotate the device then the image which is in the landscape should be shown in full screen in landscape mode of the device.

I can not attach the code because it is too large. If anyone can give an example of this it will be great.

Just imagine this my rendetitem view of flatlist, here in place of text I have an image and it should be seen in landscape mode as device orientation change to landscape.

It should not affect the pagination of flatlist when device orientation comes again in portrait.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the dimensions of the images in the FlatList when the device is rotated to landscape mode, you can add an event listener to the Dimensions API and update the state with the new dimensions like this:

```
  const [imageDimensions, setImageDimensions] = useState({
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 40,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height - 40,
  });

   useEffect(() => {
    const updateDimensions = () => {
      setImageDimensions({
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 40,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height - 40,
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        flatListRef.current?.scrollToIndex({ animated: false, index: selectedIndex });
      }, 100);
    };

    const dimensionsHandler= Dimensions.addEventListener('change', updateDimensions);

    return () => {
     dimensionsHandler.remove();
    };
  }, [selectedIndex]);

// Image code
   <Image source={{ uri: 'https://url' }} style={imageDimensions} />
```

Make sure that your flatList have this viewability Config

```
 const viewabilityConfig = useRef({
    minimumViewTime: 100,
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold: '90%',
  }).current;


  <FlatList
   ref={flatListRef}
   data={data}
   renderItem={renderItem}
   keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
   horizontal
   initialScrollIndex={selectedIndex}
   onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
   viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
   pagingEnabled />
```

You can check this working example from [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@louay12/full-screen-image-react-native).

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Hi, I checked the above code in snack. But it has problems. If the first scroll to the second index then the device rotates to landscape and comes back to again portrait, it is not working in that scenario.  What I require is that if you were in the first index then you rotate in any orientation is working fine, but if the index changes then it is not working. means the item is not showing full, there are two half items together or the scroll is moved a little forward.

Comment: If you can solve this then please help me out.

Comment: I checked above code in real device.

Comment: I've just updated the code, and you can check the snack it's supposed to work correctly :DDD

Please mark it as a correct answer and upvote it :DD

Comment: I added 8 items then, I was on the 8th and rotate the device then the 7th is showing in the landscape. and there is a better way to scroll because if there are more items then on rotation it scrolls from first to a particular image and it is not a good UX.

Comment: I've just updated the answer and the example it have to work correctly Please mark it as a correct answer and upvote it :DD

Comment: Hi, thanx it is working well in horizontal mode I need the same in vertical.

Comment: Can you just specify your issue in vertical mode and can you mark the answer as a correct answer :D

Comment: Basically, I need the same output in vertical mode as right now in horizontal. now if I only remove the horizontal then it is not working means if I am in 3rd item and then rotate the device then it is 3rd not showing and vice versa. I'll mark it correct once my actual issue is resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this issue for so so long. This code does what you need it to, but there are potential lurking bugs leaving visibleIndex out of the useEffect dependency array.

```js
  const {height, width} = useWindowDimensions();
  const [visibleIndex, setVisibleIndex] = useState(0);
  const flatListRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data.length > 0 && flatListRef.current) {
      flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({index: visibleIndex, animated: false});
    }
  }, [width, data]);

  const getItemLayout = (data, index) => ({
    length: width,
    offset: width * index,
    index,
  });

  const handleScrollEnd = event => {
    const newIndex = Math.round(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / width);
    setVisibleIndex(newIndex);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        key={width}
        ref={flatListRef}
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
        getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
        pagingEnabled={true}
        horizontal
        onMomentumScrollEnd={handleScrollEnd}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        onEndReached={fetchMoreData}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a mixed solution. In my case, I had a slider where one image was visible at a time. That's why I wait until the end of the animation when only one element remains visible. Then I set currentIndex. Then I use onContentSizeChange because it uses onLayout, so there are no races and I don't have to use timouts.

```
const handleOnViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(
  ({ viewableItems }: { viewableItems: ViewToken[] }) => {
    if (viewableItems.length === 1 && viewableItems[0].index) {
      currentIndex.current = viewableItems[0].index;
    }
  },
  [],
);

const onContentSizeChange = () => {
  if (listRef.current) {
    listRef.current.scrollToIndex({
      index: currentIndex.current,
      animated: false,
    });
  }};
```